# Retrieve everything after a split in string VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm needing to return the value of a string after it's been split in VB.Net.

The string will be something along the lines of:

```
someexpression1 OR someexpression2 OR someexpression3 OR someexpression4 OR someexpression5
```

The string can't contain more than 3 of these expressions so I need to retrieve everything after someexpression3.

After the split I would need the following "OR someexpression4 OR someexpression5", the full string will always be different lengths so I need something dynamic in order to capture the last part of the string.

Comment: Please for gods sake read the rules before posting.

Comment: If I understood correctly,Try http://hastebin.com/oxocitulud.vbs

Comment: I have no control over the number of expressions so there could, 6, 7, 8 in total it will never be the same, however I need to be able to grab everything after the third expresion

Comment: @swain90 can you show the actual string ?? and are you expecting this output `someexpression4 OR someexpression5`(with `OR`)  ?

Comment: Can you please give a short example what the string looks and what you expect after the split?

Comment: Updated to help clarify!

Answer (score 1):

Without further information on how danymic your splitting should be the following code will cover your requirement:

```
'Some UnitTest
Dim toSplit As String = "someexpression1 OR someexpression2 OR someexpression3 OR someexpression4 OR someexpression5"
Dim actual = GetLastExpressions(toSplit)
Dim expected = "OR someexpression4 OR someexpression5"
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)

toSplit = "requirement OR is OR weird"
actual = GetLastExpressions(toSplit)
expected = ""
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
'...

Private Function GetLastExpressions(expression As String, Optional splitBy As String = "OR", Optional numberToSkip As Integer = 3)
     Dim expr As String = ""
     Dim lExpressions As IEnumerable(Of String) = Nothing
     Dim aSplit = expression.Split({expression}, StringSplitOptions.None)
     If aSplit.Length > numberToSkip Then
         lExpressions = aSplit.Skip(numberToSkip)
     End If
     If lExpressions IsNot Nothing Then
         expr = splitBy & String.Join(splitBy, lExpressions)
     End If
     Return expr
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Spoke to a friend of mine who suggested this and it works fine;

```
                Dim sline As String = MyString
                Dim iorcount As Integer = 0
                Dim ipos As Integer = 1

                Do While iorcount < 17
                    ipos = InStr(ipos, sline, "OR")
                    ipos = ipos + 2
                    iorcount = iorcount + 1
                Loop
                MsgBox(Mid(sline, ipos))
```

Comment: This code will only work for a finite number of expression - which might be sufficient - but the question owner wrote that the number of expressions are dynamic